# Overlay div that snaps on overflow with parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem:**
Essentially I have a row of in-line containers with images inside them, and an overlapping div with text at the bottom of the div/image. When the window is resized *horizontally*, the image and div snap to the row below it and stay inline. However, the overlay does not snap with them until it is completely covered by the horizontal resize of the window, which only then it will snap below the row and appear with the rest of the container.

If you keep resizing the window horizontally, eventually the overlay div will snap down and appear in its correct position.

**Question:**
How can I make it, via CSS, JS or jQuery, so that the overlay div follows the container it's in when the overflow forces the containers into the next row?

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 304px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="overlay">
    Test
  </div>
  <img src="http://www.navipedia.net/images/a/a9/Example.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div id="overlay">
    Test
  </div>
  <img src="http://www.navipedia.net/images/a/a9/Example.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
</div>
```

Example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/buqbxgzz/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You are recycling IDs in your markup. **IDs must be unique** in a document. For example, use `.container` instead of `#container`.
2. Using `position: absolute` and `display: inline` on the overlay doesn't make a lot of sense, because it will be set to block level automatically (i.e. `display: block`).
3. Also, as long as you switch to `display: inline-block` on the container elements, the positioning will work. The reason is a bit convoluted, but if you look at the [elaborate description of stacking contexts by W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html), you can see that inline level elements have a very different (and probably counterintuitive) characteristics described, compared to inline-block or block elements.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 304px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    Test
  </div>
  <img src="http://www.navipedia.net/images/a/a9/Example.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    Test
  </div>
  <img src="http://www.navipedia.net/images/a/a9/Example.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
</div>
```

See fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/buqbxgzz/4/

Comment: Perfect thanks, simply just rushed the ID stuff and slipped my mind. Could've sworn I tried inline-block but apparently not! I need to sleep more. Marked this one for completeness of answer just in case anyone else has similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the width to the container instead of the overlay div node and give the latter element a 100% width. Here is the code:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 304px;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is it  working: https://jsfiddle.net/buqbxgzz/5/

Edit:

I've just realized you are using a duplicate ID in your code. ID's must be unique. Change the container and overlay to classes

Answer (score 0):

Is this the thing you are looking for? Btw, id attributes of elements should better be unique. For applying the same styling rules classes are used.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 304px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    Test
  </div>
  <img src="http://www.navipedia.net/images/a/a9/Example.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    Test
  </div>
  <img src="http://www.navipedia.net/images/a/a9/Example.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
</div>
```